# I just build android, why does it still have ios files?

Tags: react-native, expo

[Why can't it be clean?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t53Sw.png)

```
Bundle                     Size
┌ index.ios.js          8.73 MB
├ index.android.js      8.73 MB
├ index.ios.js.map      13.5 MB
└ index.android.js.map  13.6 MB
```